# Horário mensal por turnos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho de criar um botão em php para ao clicar gerar uma horário mensal de turnos, mas não estou a ver como o fazer.
Alguém consegue sugerir uma ideia?

O que estou a pensar é escolher aleatoriamente os colabores que preciso por dia de cada turno, mas está a dar erro por causa do `UNION` e o `ORDER BY`.

**Este é o código que tenho:**

```
SELECT * FROM centrodb.InfoColaboradores WHERE Turno = 'M' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8
UNION
SELECT * FROM centrodb.InfoColaboradores WHERE Turno = 'T' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM centrodb.InfoColaboradores WHERE Turno = 'T2' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT * FROM centrodb.InfoColaboradores WHERE Turno = 'N' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
```

**Esta é a minha estrutura das tabelas:**

1- Tabela DiasSemana com os campos: id, Dias.
Nesta tabela coloquei todos os dias da semana como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2- Tabela H_Turno com os seguintes campos: id, Turno, H_Inicio, H_fim.
Tabela com o inicio e fim de cada turno como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3- Tabela InfoColaboradores com os seguintes campos: id, NomeColaborador, Turno, Horadia.
Esta indica o turno de cada colaborador e as horas que pode fazer por dia como mostra a imagem:

Será que tenho a estrutura das tabelas bem criadas?

A ideia agora é criar horário mensal aleatório e automaticamente, onde no turno da manhã só pode ter 8 colaboradores, o da tarde 4 colaboradores, o da tarde2 3 colaboradores e da noite 2 colaboradores.

**Regras:**
Se trabalhar 4 dias seguidos 1 folga, se for 5 dias 2 folgas.
Trabalhar um domingo de 2 em 2 meses

Utilizei o código acima onde com o `Rand()` consigo criar a primeira seleção aleatória de cada turno.

Desta forma consigo iniciar só a gerar automaticamente para o primeiro dia e só para o turno da manhã, mas ainda sem regras, **exemplo de código:**

```
SELECT NomeColaborador, centrodb.H_Turno.Turno, centrodb.H_Turno.H_inicio, centrodb.H_Turno.H_Fim, MONTH(NOW())
FROM centrodb.InfoColaboradores LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.H_Turno
ON centrodb.H_Turno.Turno = centrodb.InfoColaboradores.Turno
WHERE centrodb.H_Turno.Turno = 'M' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8
```

Como gerar este turno automaticamente para o mês e não só para um dia?

Comment: É importante que você coloque os trechos mais relevantes do que você já tem feito.

Comment: Não tenho código ainda nenhum, porque não estou a conseguir ver uma forma de o fazer. Não conseguem colocar um exemplo?  Uma das regras é criar o horário por turnos mensal, se o colaborador trabalhar 4 dias seguidos folga um, se trabalhar 5 dias seguidos folga dois e tentar que todos pelo menos trabalhe um domingo de dois em dois meses.

Comment: Esta faltado as regras necessárias para criar essa função. Isso é um problema clássico de computação chamado problema da mochila.

Comment: Veja, que a partir do momento que se tem exato controle do problema, se tem o controle da solução. Antes de partir para o código, rabisque bastante e crie escalas na mão. Quando conseguir fazer isso no papel, será muito facil passar isso para o código

Uma dica que te dou é tentar utilizar soluções simples, como escala escalonada, onde se cria uma "escada" de folgas e variações. mas como disse, tenha o controle do problema e entenda como resolver isso  primeiro , pois cada caso é um caso

Um bom ponto de partida https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8dHReSgSQY

Comment: Meu caro, em primeiro lugar, recomendo que simplifique suas regras de negócio, por causa das seguintes situações: (1) Se está difícil de entender e implementar, será ainda mais difícil modificar quando novas regras ou cruzamentos futuros surgirem; (2) Se você precisar implementar um log de como o sistema gerou a escala, pra se prevenir contra ações judiciais, será quase impossível; (3) Se alguém precisar faltar e você precisar remanejar a escala, terá sérios problemas; (4) Você irá perder muito tempo e esforço de desenvolvimento em uma situação que entrega pouco valor pro cliente. Simplifque.

Comment: Comece pensando pela regra mais longa. Se você tem regra para cada 2 meses, a regra tem que rodar no mínimo os 2 meses após o comando. Se eu entendi bem, é o mesmo que o trabalhador trabalhar 1 domingo mês sim e no outro não. Todos os trabalhadores irão revezar este domingo a ser trabalhado? O estabelecimento funciona 24hrs 7 dias por semana?

Answer (score -3):

```
$turno = array('M'=>8,'T'=>4,'T2'=>3,'N'=>2);
foreach($turnos as $turno=>$cargos){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.InfoColaboradores WHERE Turno='' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($CONN,$sql);
    for($x=0;$x<$cargos;$x++){
      $funcionario = mysqli_result($resultado,$x,'Id');
      //atualiza o turno do funcionário
      $sql = "UPDATE centrodb.InfoColaboradores SET Turno='$turno' WHERE Id='$funcionario'";
      mysqli_query($CONN,$sql);
      //prioriza 4 dias seguidos pois paga menos folga guarda domingo para gerar depois
      for($y=0;$y<6;$y++){
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela_turnos (Ano_Mes,Semana,Turno,Funcionario) VALUES ('$data','$y','$turno','$funcionario');
        mysqli_query($CONN,$sql);
       }
}}
```

correndo o risco de tomar uma exclusão... segue o rabisco temporário